# How to store array of strings in database table using Hibernate?

Tags: database, string, oracle

Let's say i have `array of`Strings`= {"testUser1", "testUser2", ... , "testUser28"}`, how do  I store this in oracle database, am using `varchar2` as dataType for `userTableColumn`.

My question:

1. How do I store this array of string, for ex, in oracle Database using Hibernate (any example would be highly appreciated) ?
2. What should be dataType of database column that will store this array of string, right now i have that as `varchar2`, also if I define it as `clob` then unless size is greater than `4000 bytes`, it would behave as `varchar2` and size exceeds 4000 bytes, it would be converted to `clob`?

Comment: Is this possible, if not, what are other alternatives for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Oracle database end should look like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_array AS
VARRAY (30) OF VARCHAR2(1000);

CREATE TABLE my_table (my_array string_array);
```

Can't provide example for Hibernate though.